# Should hydrogen peroxide be applied on a bloody nose?

Tags: hematology, medicine

When I was a kid, my parents taught me to apply hydrogen peroxide on my nose whenever it bled. It's a rare event, but my nose bleeds from time to time, and when it does, I always go through the same procedure of dipping a cotton bud in hydrogen peroxide, and applying it to the inside of the bleeding nostril. It always stops the bleeding immediately and I get on with my day.

It happened right now, and since I always just go through the motions without thinking about it, today I was curious about the principles at stake here. In looking for an answer about why it does what it does, I found only references to the effects of drinking hydrogen peroxide, which looks like a controversial subject whose benefits may be non-existent; but I didn't find a single mention about the application of hydrogen peroxide directly on a bleeding nose, which made me worried if what I'm doing is even recommended or if I'm doing something potentially dangerous.

So my question is: is this practice beneficial, and why?

---

**Update:** This question mentioned oxygenated water, which is the literal translation of "água oxigenada" (PT), but apparently that's only the commercial name for "peróxido de hidrogénio" where I live, which translates to hydrogen peroxide (H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub>); and since that returns many more hits on google, I've renamed all instances of oxygenated water to hydrogen peroxide in this question.

Comment: I'll doubt it. Oxygen is taken up via the lungs, water is not supporting the coagulation process of the blood, it prolongs the time as it dissolves the first (and pretty fragile) aggregates.

Comment: What is oxygenated water?

Comment: oxygenated water is water that has more oxygen diluted, with process, I believe, similar to that of carbonated water production

Comment: After some digging, I realized that a more accurate name would be hydrogen peroxide. I added an update at the end of the question with more details.

Comment: The main reason to use hydrogen peroxide is simply to "decoagulate" the exposed blood across the nasal cavities. 

Human blood naturally coagulates to protect exposed areas and inhibit further blood loss -- kind of like a bandage. It can be a problem, however, when this coagulated bandage gets in the way of the tissue underneath from fully healing and completely restoring itself (as it was previously). 

Hence we can use hydrogen peroxide to take off these bandages whenever needed.

Comment: Otherwise, keeping these coagulations in the nose for too long is just a ticking time bomb for an even bigger nosebleed --- that is, when we decide to blow our noses (or pick them) some time afterwards, for whatever reason, and these coagulations simply...pop out!

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think oxygenated water does anything to stop bloody noses. But holding a wet cotton swab with pressure to the inside of the nose might.

The vast majority of bloody noses in healthy individuals arise from one specific area in the nose (on either side):

[image]

In the mucosa of the nasal septum (the cartilagenous structure separating the nose into two sides), there is an area where several arteries "meet", giving it an exceptionally rich vascular supply, called Kiesselbach's plexus. It is on the anterior surface, and exposed to dry air and trauma (even such as might be sustained by a bad cold). Bleeding typically occurs when the mucosa erodes for any reason, and the capillaries and venules (and sometimes arterioles) become exposed and subsequently break. The result is the familiar bloody dripping of a nosebleed.

The most common treatment is *direct pressure* (squeezing the sides of the nose together) for 5-10 minutes. This works because putting direct pressure on any bleed stops the blood flow long enough for a clot to form and the arteriole to close down.
If needed, more aggressive control can be achieved by a professional.

If you happen to apply pressure with the wet cotton swab to a large enough part of the plexus (or somewhere near the spot from which your nose is bleeding), your nosebleed will stop. But it really doesn't matter what you use to wet the cotton swab (plain water, oxygenated water, carbonated water (ouch!), or other. (*Noted: OP added that the liquid is hydrogen peroxide. This is not a good idea as it is an irritant and actually can cause mucosal damage.*) Sufficient pressure and clot formation (and subsequent tenderness with the nose) is all that is needed.*

What doesn't work:

- icepacks to the neck
- leaning your head forward (increases blood flow) or back (may cause the blood to flow into your throat)
- lying down (increases blood flow)
- frequent 'peeking' to see if bleeding has stopped
- a dry object placed against the area of bleeding (it will break up the clot when pulled away from the septum)

Aftercare and prevention is another subject.

Note: The safest way to end a common nosebleed is by squeezing as much of the 'rubbery' portion of the nose together for up to 30 minutes if necessary. Putting something into your nose poses the risk of infection.

*more serious or recurrent bleeding needs medical attention

Comment: IMO You should refrain from giving medical advice. For the same reasons as asking for one. This is not really an advice per se but it encourages these kind of posts.

Answer (score 1):

Hydrogen peroxide, very potent oxidant, is used in case of skin cutting, small wounds etc. I think, firstly, It helps by killing bacteria that might otherwise cause infection. I couldn't find evidence of hydrogen peroxide promoting clot formation.

However, being an oxidative agent, H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> might be very harmful to gentle epithelium of nose. Theoretically, it can destroy it by chemical burns. Imagine pouring acid into your throat or intestines, it will definitely not be good.

You don't find information on applicating of H<sub>2</sub>O<sub>2</sub> to bleeding noses because it is very harmful in first place.